# Java swt canvas how does the paint listener work?

Tags: java, canvas, swt, 2d

I've just started working with swt's canvas. I'm under the impression that draw commands from the graphics controller (gc) can be executed in any listener that is attached to the canvas. I guess though, my question is what triggers the paint listener method `paintControl`?

Does the `canvas.redraw()` cause this to run as well?

Thanks for anyone who can point me in the right direction. If there are tutorials or books I can read on the matter(2d drawing in swt in general as well), I would love to hear of them.

**EDIT:**
Here is the code, I'm running into an issue where the graphCanvas is not filling excess vertical space? It doesn't work when I have it fill excessHorizontal space either. But it seems to work when I apply those properties to the composites. Any idea?

```
Color black = Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK);
    chartComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout chartGridLayout = new GridLayout(1,false);
    GridData chartGridData = new GridData();
    chartGridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    chartGridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;

    chartComposite.setLayout(chartGridLayout);
    chartComposite.setLayoutData(chartGridData);

    chartInnerComposite = new Composite(chartComposite, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout chartInnerGridLayout = new GridLayout(2,false);
    GridData chartInnerGridData = new GridData();
    chartInnerGridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    chartInnerGridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
    chartInnerComposite.setLayout(chartInnerGridLayout);
    chartInnerComposite.setLayoutData(chartInnerGridData);
    /**
     * Create the four canvases
     */

    Canvas yCanvas = new Canvas(chartInnerComposite, SWT.None);
    graphCanvas = new Canvas(chartInnerComposite, SWT.None);
    GridLayout graphGridLayout = new GridLayout(1, false);
    graphGridLayout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = false;
    GridData graphGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL);
    graphGridData.widthHint = 400;
    graphGridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
    graphCanvas.setLayout(graphGridLayout);
    graphCanvas.setLayoutData(graphGridData);
    graphCanvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            e.gc.drawLine(20, 20, 500, 500);
            e.gc.drawRectangle(0, 0, graphCanvas.getSize().x -1, graphCanvas.getSize().y -1);

            e.gc.drawLine(0, 40, 500, 500);
            e.gc.drawLine(0, 0, 0, 1200);
            e.gc.drawLine(0, 0, 1200, 0);               
        }
    });
    /*graphCanvas.setSize(400, 400);
    graphCanvas.redraw();
    graphCanvas.update();*/


    Canvas filler = new Canvas(chartInnerComposite, SWT.NONE);
    Canvas xCanvas = new Canvas(chartInnerComposite, SWT.None);
```

Comment: I don't understand your last question. Can you please provide a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/). Then I can run it myself and try to help you.

Comment: I am able to use the widthHint and heightHint to give the canvas a manual size. But I am unable to have the canvas stretch both excess vertical and horizontal space.

Comment: You should really provide an SSCCE. Otherwise I will have to guess what's going wrong...

Comment: I'm developing with Eclipse RCP framework and the code above is about as self contained as I can imagine it being?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can definitely call canvas.redraw() manually, which will then trigger a paintControl event.  SWT itself will also cause repaints to be triggered as needed, for things like window resizing and when the canvas gets obscured/un-obscured by other windows.

Comment: Thank you, how do I re-size the canvas? When I use canvas.setSize(w,h); The code seems to do nothing? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: The trick with resizing of child components in SWT is always in the layout, particularly it seems like using GridLayout.  I would recommend doing one of two patterns:  Either use the default GridData constructor with no arguments or the one with four arguments (horizAlign,vertAlign,grabHoriz,grabVert).  The solution in your case might be to just move to "new GridData (SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true)".

Comment: You hit the mark with that answer. I was only setting either the horizontalAlignment or horizontalGrabExcessSpace at a time. Getting that weird stuff going on.